# Parse HTML page using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I want to parse an external html page using `cURL`.
This is my simple code :

```
$ch=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
$data=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But i don't know how to access and echo my wish tag (for example a `div` with `class="news"`)
**Note**:I don't want to use`simple_html_dom`.it's slower than cURL and causes some errors for me.

Comment: [Dont try to parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: What is this ? explain please.

Comment: cURL has nothing to do with parsing, it is just a library for fetching data over the network. The statement that simple_html_dom is slower than cURL therefore makes no sense, and this question is too open-ended to be answerable (it boils down to "how should I find something in HTML?")

Comment: IMSoP: I said i don't know how to parse received data.

Comment: @AliN11 You need to be more specific about what you're asking. There are lots of ways to parse HTML, but asking for all of them is too broad a question for this site. You mention you had problems with `simple_html_dom`, but don't say what they are; perhaps you could ask a question to help solve those problems? Either way, cURL is definitely not relevant, as it just gives you a string of HTML, just like if you'd loaded it from a local file.

Answer (score 1):

`simple_html_dom` is not slow. You can do your work like below;

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$url =''; // Put your crawl url here
$news = array();
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach ($html->find('div') as $div){
    if ($div->getAttribute('class') == "news")
    array_push($news, $div->getAttribute('class'));
}

echo implode("\n ", $news);
```

Comment: You need to provide url to $url, also be sure that you have sşmple_html_dom.php

Comment: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Please provide valid url to $url, see my updated answer

Comment: If you are familiar, you need to know that "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" means your url is unreachable or invalid

Comment: But you said that page is html, this page is xml.Please update your question

Comment: There is no "div" with class "news".

Comment: Try `div.desc` .No difference `news` or `desc`.I can't open this url using this method.

Comment: have you tried curl -L http://favanews.com/index.aspx/n/10624 in order to check connectivity? You need to be able to connect that url first

Comment: Thank you bro.I think this problem of url.But i want to know: cURL is faster or this method ?

Comment: Thank you and sorry for bad english today (:

Comment: curl is different. Curl is only for getting response from endpoint url. In order to parse it, you need to use regular expressions on php. curl doesn't parse. If it worked for you, you can set my answer helpful.

Comment: By using `file_get_html($url)` you are combining two separate things: fetching the data from the URL, and parsing the result of that fetch. If you use cURL or some other method to fetch the data, you can use `str_get_html` instead. This has nothing to do with being "slower", though.